# A gentle introduction to CFT

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory

1) Which is the definition of a conformal field theory?

2) Which are the physical prerequisites one would need to start studying conformal field theories?
(i.e Does one need to know supersymmetry? Does one need non-perturbative effects such as solitons, instantons etc?)

3) Which are the mathematical prerequisites one would need to start studying conformal field theories?
(i.e how much complex analysis should one know? Does one need the theory of Riemann Surfaces? Does one need algebraic topology or algebraic geometry? And how much?)

4) Which are the best/most common books, or review articles, for a gentle introduction on the topic, at second/third year graduate level?

5) Do CFT models have an application in real world (already experimentally tested) physics?
(Also outside the high energy framework, maybe in condensed matter, etc.)

Comment: That's a lot of questions, and 5) is off-topic. Maybe start with a reference request for 1), on its own, with suitable background as to what you know already. I changed the tags to something more appropriate.

Comment: @Federico. You wrongly assume that there is a unique mathematical definition of CFT. There are many (I know three). Probably all good. And people don't know how to compare them (at a mathematical level of rigor). The mathematical prerequisites are very different depending on which approach to CFT you decide to study. Also, there is an important distinction between "chiral CFT" and "full CFT": those are two completely different things (but not unrelated).

Comment: This is probably irrelevant since this question is already closed, but I'll just note that it's a cross-post of [a question which was put on hold on Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82573/a-gentle-introduction-to-cft).

Comment: @Logan Maingi I believed that different places have different rules on what can or can not be posted. Is it really bad to crosspost if it did not work there?

Please I am not trying to be arrogant, just trying to understand, since it is my first time in both of these places

Comment: @FedericoCarta Yes, different sites have different standards, and cross-posting isn't always bad. However, cross-posting immediately is frowned upon, whether or not the question was closed. [This MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/) details the proper protocol for if you think you posted on the wrong site. Immediately cross-posting a closed question to a different site with no indication that it is a cross-post can come across as trying to game the system (I don't thin this was your intention). At minimum you should try to improve your post there first before reposting it here.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the advice.
I was only trying to get some answers and maybe stimulate a good discussion.

Comment: @FedericoCarta I'll also note that questions should be tailored to the community. The original questions you posted were decent for physicists, though they were too broad together and should have been split up. However, if you're going to ask the same question on a site for research mathematicians, you need to be more tailored to that community. CFTs are of interest to mathematicians as well as physicists, but the literature in the two disciplines is quite different. I'm not sure which one you wanted to learn, but if it's the physics version this would probably not be the right place to ask.

Comment: What's with the hate for this question?  Regarding (1), there's a paper of Segal titled ``The definition of conformal field theory'' that might be relevant.  As for (2), (3), (4), I would very much like an answer myself.  I also think (2), (3), (4) are just reformulations / aspects of / clarifications of the same underlying question, so the complaint that there's too many questions here is just absurd.

Comment: @Federico: For references try Gaberdiel's review paper on conformal field theories. For commented pointers to the literature see here ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conformal+field+theory Or for one rigorous definition and derivation of the full theory from the first principles see the book by P. Di Francesco, P. Mathieu and D. Senechal, Conformal Field Theory (Springer, 1997) (and this is my source).

Comment: @LoganMaingi maybe you have noted this: Physics SE still closes any reference-request (reference-request defined as any researcher or advanced student would naturally use that term conversely to the strange way too restrictive definition of that tag on Physics SE) in particular about advanced theoretical topics immediately, even though this should no longer happen due to the new so-called "books or recommendation policy" they have. But it still does happen. So editing that question over there would be completely pointless, reference questions about advanced topics are simply not tolerated.

Comment: @Dilaton I agree that this question would not be accepted by Physics SE standards, but I don't think that immediately makes it acceptable on MathOverflow. MathOverflow is a site for professional mathematicians. While physicists and physics questions are sometimes welcome, we aren't the intended audience. As this question is right now, this is the wrong venue IMO (though there do seem to be some above who disagree). This question's closing on PSE may be an argument for creating a different Physics Q&A site or changing the rules there, but not for changing the rules here just to accommodate us.

Comment: @LoganMaingi yes I just wanted to point out the desolate situation on Physics SE we both know I guess, and the new higher level physics site (outside SE) is work in progress, I hope we will go online early next year. I did by no means want to overreach my position and presume the MO community should chance any rules. Though sometimes I wish out of desparation that advanced theoretical physics content could apply for asylum at a better more friendly and welcoming place not dominated by bad political overmoderation somewhere, until our new site is running...

Comment: Concerning 5) there are applications of CFT in the context of 2d conformal turbulence. I can look up the references later, if you are interested.

Comment: I answered this in http://www.physicsoverflow.org/5198